# String function in react

Tags: javascript, string

I want to get the word after the @ from the string like. "hello coders am @ayub a beginner in react". want to get that (ayub) from the string after @. any help.

Comment: Would the regex `/(@.+?)\b/g` work for you? - not sure if the `\b` is needed though

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `String.prototype.indexOf` and `String.prototype.substring`

```js
let data = "hello coders am @ayub a beginner in react";
let startIndex = data.indexOf('@');
let endIndex = data.indexOf(' ', (startIndex + 1));

let result = data.substring(startIndex+1, endIndex);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do not need a React specific function to do that. You can write a simple javascript function like so -

```js
function getName(str) {
  return str.match(/@[a-z]+/)[0].substring(1);
}
console.log(getName("hello coders am @ayub a beginner in react"));
```

This is a pretty fast solution